# How to merge an HFS+ partition into my APFS partition

Tags: partition, apfs, hfs+, macos

I want to merge an empty HFS+ partition with my Mac's APFS partition. My Disk Utility interface looks like this :

[image]

How can I do this ?

Comment: @klanomath not restore I used the wrong verb  sorry,  it is already empty, just merge it into my macos partition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Choose the internal drive (Apple HDD...)
2. Hit "Partition" in the top row
3. Choose the *freeMacPartition* slice of the pie
4. Hit the <kbd>-</kbd>-button and then the <kbd>Apply</kbd>-button

The freeMacPartition has to be located downstream of (or "after") the APFS container in the partition table or merging won't work.